# Laravel / Livewire form upload issues with Base64 PDF

Tags: laravel, base64, guzzle, laravel-livewire

As the title suggests, I want to send a Base64 application/pdf file to an external service via Guzzle. However, each uploaded file shows me the application/octet-stream mime type. This implies a 400 response from the service, which requires application/pdf as the mime type. How can I set the format correctly?

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', "https://baseurl/{$id}/documents", [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => "file",
            'filename' => "test.pdf",
            'contents' => "data:application/pdf;name={$params->getClientOriginalName()};base64,{$encoded}",
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'nature',
            'contents' => 'attachment'
        ]
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'accept' => 'application/json',
        'authorization' => 'Bearer 1234',
    ],
]);
```

[uploaded file dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE8NN.png)

Service response when i try to upload the file with Guzzle:

> {"type":"parameters_not_valid","detail":"You have some invalid params
> in your payload.","invalid_params":[{"name":"file","reason":"The mime
> type of the file is invalid (\u0022text/plain\u0022). Allowed mime
> types are \u0022application/pdf\u0022,
> \u0022application/acrobat\u0022, \u0022application/nappdf\u0022,
> \u0022application/x-pdf\u0022, \u0022image/pdf\u0022."}]}

Comment: Is there any documentation you can share? It seems your payload isn't valid for this external service